# UNIX - Add column at the end of CSV with double quotes using SED

Tags: linux, sed, csv

I have data in following format :

```
"1";"abc"
"2";"dfg"
"3";"hij"
```

I used the following command to add a column:

```
sed "s/$/;"newc"/" file.csv
```

but i get the last column without quotes:

```
"1";"abc";newc
"2";"dfg";newc
"3";"hij";newc
```

can not figure out how to update it to add double quotes
and get:

```
"1";"abc";"newc"
"2";"dfg";"newc"
"3";"hij";"newc"
```

Comment: Surrounding sed script with single quotes doesn't work? `'s/$/;"newc"/'`

Comment: yes, it worked! sorry, was simpler than I thought.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved [in comments](https://superuser.com/q/1403129/432690#comment2116270_1403129) without proper explanation:

> Surrounding sed script with single quotes doesn't work? `'s/$/;"newc"/'`

> yes, it worked!

This answer is going to shed some light on what happened and why the solution works.

---

In your original command quoting goes like this:

```
sed "s/$/;"newc"/" file.csv
#   ^     ^        a matching pair of quotes
#              ^ ^ another pair of quotes
#    s/$/;      /  these fragments are quoted
#          newc    this fragment is not quoted at all
```

The quotes you used are consumed by the shell. Their presence tells the shell to treat quoted strings somewhat differently than non-quoted ones, e.g. the quoted semicolon (`;`) is not a command separator; then they disappear, i.e. the shell doesn't pass them to `sed`.

Note `newc` contains no characters special to the shell, it behaves in the same way whether it's quoted or not. This means `newc` might as well be quoted, like this:

```
sed "s/$/;""newc""/" file.csv
#          ^    ^    added pair of quotes
```

But this is equivalent to

```
sed "s/$/;newc/" file.csv
```

and after the shell consumes the quotes `sed` gets these arguments: `s/$/;newc/`, `file.csv`. As you can see the tool gets no quotes at all.

To pass quotes to `sed` you need to make them "survive" parsing done by the shell. There are few ways to do this. Two common approaches:

1. Escaping with `\`. Inside double quotes you can escape a double quote character, so it is treated as a part of the quoted string, not as a closing quote. In your case:

   ```
   sed "s/$/;\"newc\"/" file.csv
   ```
2. Mixing quotes. A double quote inside single quotes remains. The mentioned solution uses this fact:

   ```
   sed 's/$/;"newc"/' file.csv
   ```

   A single quote inside double quotes also remains. E.g. if you need to pass a literal `'"` argument to `echo`, this will work:

   ```
   echo "'"'"'
   #    ^ ^    # a pair of double quotes that make the single quote survive
   #       ^ ^ # a pair of single quotes that make the double quote survive
   ```

---

Sometimes it's good to invoke `set -x` before a "misbehaving" command to learn what is left after the shell parses it. Your original command and two fixed ones generate this (output from `sed` omitted for clarity):

```
$ sed "s/$/;"newc"/" file.csv       # original command
+ sed s/$/;newc/ file.csv
$ # the above line contains what sed really got
$ sed "s/$/;\"newc\"/" file.csv     # fixed
+ sed s/$/;"newc"/ file.csv
$ # this time sed got the right string
$ sed 's/$/;"newc"/' file.csv       # also fixed
+ sed s/$/;"newc"/ file.csv
$ # again the right string
$
```

Note: at the end invoke `set +x` to revert what `set -x` did.